# Does Apple Aperture have a way to change the exposure of many files at once?

Tags: apple-aperture, timelapse, batch

I'm just editing a time lapse video I shot and have to change the exposure on about 1000 files. Is there a way in Apple Aperture to batch edit files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In Aperture it's called lift and stamp. Apple have a video explaining how to do just that [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/VI178).